# Visual Studio Code gives me "#include error detected" for C

Tags: c, visual-studio, path

I have started to learn `c`, I tried to use it with VSCode, but the `#include <stdio.h>` is highlighted in green with this error message:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit
(C:\Users\Jerlam\Desktop\C\training\dweight.c) will be provided by the
Tag Parser.

could not open source file "stdio.h" (no directories in search list)
```

I have seen some topics about this issue, but none of them helped me to fix it.
Here is my `c_cpp_properties.json` file in which I have to add the path (of `stdio`). In fact the documentation about it is absolutely not beginner friendly.

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10240.0/ucrt"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
        ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have added manually this path:

> "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10240.0/ucrt"

because it contains the `stdio.h` header.

What shall I do? Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using the mingw-w64 compiler, I would assume that the correct version of `stdio.h` would be the one in `c:\\mingw-w64\\include`? I know nothing about Windows or VS, but that looks wrong to me.

Comment: Ups sorry, I added myself this line of code that I took from another post. This line is not there originally. I installed mingw, but it turns out that there is no include folder in C:/mingw/ ...

Comment: Does compiling the project work or does it also fail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this video on how to [Set Up C++ Development With Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 (VS Code)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIw02CaEusY).

1. I launched **MinGW Installation Manager** and installed all the package from the **Basic Setup**.
2. I added the path of the gcc compiler to my system´s environment variables: `C:\MinGW\bin`, in which is the `gcc.exe`.
3. I opened the c_cpp_properties.json file and added different paths for the folders I want to include. So now my `c_cpp_properties.json` file looks like this:

   ```json
   {
       "configurations": [{
           "name": "Win32",
           "includePath": [
               "${workspaceFolder}/**",
               "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt",
               "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\include",
               "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0",
               "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++",
               "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include"
           ],
           "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
           "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
       }],
       "version": 4
   }
   ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20613793)

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski I am sorry, I am not completly used to stackoverflow. My solution was edited.

Comment: regarding this statement:

    `#include < stdio.h>`

This does not have the proper syntax.  There should be no spaces between the `<` nor `>` and the name of the header file

Comment: @user3629249 I put a space because otherwise it does not display anything, I don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

(Updated the answer)

Anyone else coming here, note VS Code keeps caches. If even after making changes to your `c_cpp_properties.json` the error doesn't go away. Try deleting the cache for your workspace (aka directory).

For,

**Windows:** `C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedData\*`

**Linux:**

Comment: I think that may have fixed it... Thanks... By the way, the VSCode setting for the IntelliSense path is `C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath`. (On Linux, I navigated into it, found a folder named `/ipch/`, and ran `sudo rm -r ipch`.)

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me, running VSCode on Windows 10.

1. Go to your project folder
2. Open .vscode subfolder
3. Go to c_cpp_properties.json
4. Replace everything you have in that file with this code:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "MinGW",

        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

5. Save and restart the IDE.

Comment: "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64" is now also a possibility

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you have visual studio and code together on your pc. Just try to uninstall all C and C++ extensions from apps list, visual studio and visual studio code on your pc then restart and again install the vs code. I wasted my whole day behind it but no JSON file did work for me. you only need to put the MinGW-64/bin path in JSON file on vs code where ever you have installed the MinGW-64 on your pc.
if you do not have MinGW on your pc I am putting a video link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HD0pqVtsmw

Answer (score 0):

I use C in Ubuntu windows WSL. Here is my config for VSCcode to work:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "WSL",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                    "/usr/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```