# VS Code cannot find a header, already in PATH and in settings.json

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, path, include

I know this is one of the most common questions here, but I couldn't make the already existing answers work for me.

I am trying the set my VS Code to work with C. So, as a proof of concept, I run this sophisticated code:

```c
#include "io.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello");
}
```

Obvious from the title, I receive this error message:

```
fatal error C1034: io.h: no include path set
```

Visually inspecting, io.h is in the folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\` which is included in the `Path`.

So, I looked for other solutions. A few of the answers suggested editing the `settings.json`. So, I added all the folders including all the header files to the `settings.json`. Note that all of these folders are also in the `Path`.

```c
"C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\",
    "C:\\DEV\\vcpkg\\installed\\x86-windows\\include\\",
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\include\\"
  ],
```

The include path of VS Code looks like this.

[image]
For the sake of completeness, I also include my PATH variable here. [image]

Some answers mentioned checking the compiler as well. ```gcc --version`` output is as follows:

```
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I restarted my computer each time I edited `Path`. I don't know what else to do.

The questions on stackoverflow that I already tried to make work are: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151872/pyconfig-h59-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-include-stdio-h-saying-add-include-path-to-settings), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616834/vcruntime-h-missing-from-windows-include-folder), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883754/visual-studio-code-gives-me-include-error-detected-for-c) and a few more that I can't find now.

I apologise if there is an obvious solution that I miss, yet I already spent two days to solve this on my own.

Thanks