# vscode won't show the arguments for functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

So a couple of days ago, I installed vscode for working with the Unity game engine scripts, however, even though I installed the C# extension, it won't show the arguments for each function, for example, if I write an `AddForce()` function, vscode doesn't show what kind of arguments should I put inside the parenthesis. How can I get it to do so?

Say, it won't show the arguments for `AddForce()` in this code I wrote:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb; //References the player's Rigid Body component as "rb"

    void Update()
    {
        rb.AddForce();
    }
}
```

Also, vscode shows this error whenever I load a script from my Unity project:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzr5z.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO,  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would let others to help you faster. In the other hand, you should post your class and `AddForce` and a minimum use code snippet on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end, I installed the SDK that can be found at: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net471-developer-pack-offline-installer and now Intellisense is working perfectly and I can see the arguments for each function properly. Also, I directly opened the folder where my Unity project scripts were at and apparently that helped too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? 
Need a `project.json` file or `*.sln` in your project. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979730/13616364

Comment: Well, my Unity project folder does have a *.sln file, however, when I try to open it with vscode, arguments still don't show up, and same goes for trying to open the folder in which the *.sln file is contained...

Comment: Do you have multiple? You may need to select a specific one (as in the guide above) if VScode is confused which it should use.

Comment: multiple? As in multiple *.sln files? Nope, there's only one on my Unity project folder. Also, sorry if I don't follow too much on this. I'm new to programming and all..