# How to get autocomplete code and highlight syntax in Node.js on VScode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I started to learn Node.js recently, and I've notice a difference between my VScode IDE vs the guides on YouTube or other places VScode IDE

for example I want to write the following code `const names = require('./names')`

Language mode is set to **JavaScript**

**1. I want the the IDE will complete the code when I write `require` Like every IDE**

[image: no autocomplete]

**2. after I write it, it's not highlighted like a normal piece of code.**

My IDE:

[image: My IDE]

Some instructor IDE:

[image: Some instructor IDE]

Comment: You should read [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/visual-studio-code-for-node.js-development).

Comment: @SercanSebetçi This article does not help me at all!

Comment: After installing the plugins, you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975152/intellisense-not-automatically-working-vscode/29979730#29979730) to get intellisense active.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Sorry, doesn't fix the Autocomplete (Intellisense) and the Highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [Node.js Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=waderyan.nodejs-extension-pack) in Visual Studio Code Editor.
2. Then install the [Node.js Modules Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leizongmin.node-module-intellisense) plug-in in Visual Studio Code Editor.

The image below belongs to the test study I made after installing the plugins I mentioned above. You can review [this article](https://dev.to/mccauley/a-practical-introduction-to-setting-up-a-nodejs-express-web-project-with-vscode-220h) to create the test project.

[image: Application Test Image]

[Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) must be installed on the system for all the processes I mentioned above to work. To check:

```sh
> node --version
v14.17.6
> npm --version
v6.14.15
```

Comment: Thank you, I do have the autocomplate (even if its not accurate) but I still don't have the heighted syntax