# How to enable intellisense in VS Code for C# when .net sdk installed via snap

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp, snap

I've downloaded this extension:
[screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnHAC.png)

Working folder is selected, .csproj is selected. I did enable and disabled the extension, restarted VS Code, but still it didnt help.
There are only keywords that i'm using in the list, but no any System.Object and other types functionality available: [screen image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKv4L.png)

upd: Forgot to mention that my sdk and runtime installed via snap tool, so .net sdk path is */snap/dotnet-sdk/167/sdk/5.0.408/*
Could snap be the problem, if yes, how to fix it?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975152/intellisense-not-automatically-working-vscode

Comment: Not quite helpful. Could it be problem because I've installed .net sdk via snap and so there is a problem with the figuring out the right path?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe omnisharp extension has wrong default path or something and it's the problem? 
In settings "use modern net" option is true, but every path was empty. I tried:
Omnisharp: Dotnet path: /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet
Omnisharp: Sdk Path: /snap/dotnet-sdk/167/sdk/5.0.408
Omnisharp: Sdk version: 5.0.408
but still doesn't work. Either first option "dotnet path" is wrong or idk what could possibly be wrong in the first place

Comment: sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet also didnt help

Answer (score 2):

Omg, changed version of omnisharp extension from newest to v1.24.4 and it helped.....

Answer (score 1):

After updating Omnisharp version to v1.25.0, it was not able to locate MSBuild for me. I have installed [.Net 6.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) and omnisharp was able to locate MSBuild from there.

The older version of Omnisharp has MSBuild available within their extension install folder    C:\Users\Username.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-XX.XX.XX....omnisharp\X.XX.XX\msbuild