# Why is my visual studio code not displaying my errors or intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-code

No matter what c# script i boot up, no errors are displayed and neither is IntelliSense.

[image]

I've reinstalled vsc, reinstalled some extensions, made sure errors are turned on but nothing seems to work.

They work fine in regular vs but not vsc.

Comment: Have you installed the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)? I'm pretty sure it will only highlight your code otherwise.

Comment: yup, c# extension is installed, one of the first things I checked

Answer (score 0):

VScode by default only support web technologies if you want to use it for other programming languages you have to install microsoft dedicated extension for that technology like - [C# for VScode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)

Comment: I am aware of this and the errors used to work and so did intellisense however when i booted up vsc a few days ago they just stopped working.

Comment: Does this solve your problem - [Intelisense VScode C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975152/intellisense-not-automatically-working-vscode)?

Comment: unfortunatly no, after following everything there, nothing has changed